# Как сделать скролл внизу?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Подскажите скрипт или что-то еще подобное, чтобы при загрузке страницы скролл был всегда внизу, т.е. есть блок, он на авто полосе прокрутке, но нужно, чтобы он был всегда внизу.
Нашел что-то такое вот, но тут скорее к textarea было обращение

```
var txt = document.getElementById("ваша текстареа");
     hg  = txt.clientHeight + txt.scrollTop;

txt.scrollTop(hg);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PdxrA/

Comment: Странно, но скрипт не работает
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
   window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
 </script>
И ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0):

Если ничего не выходит с jquery, вы можете использовать такой метод:

```
<div class='content>
  много текста...
  много текста...
  много текста...
 <div id='bottom'></div>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
 location.href = '#bottom';
</script>
```